# getting config value in cms pages magento2

Tags: magento2, system-configuration

I have added a custom field in system->configuration. The code is below.

```
<tab id="testtab">
            <label>Test settings</label>
        </tab>
        <section id="testsection" type="text" showInDefault="1">
            <label>Test Configuration</label>
            <tab>testtab</tab>
            <resource>Namespace_Modulename::system_config</resource>
            <group id="settings" type="text"  sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1">
                <label>Credentials</label>
                <field id="key" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="30" showInDefault="1">
                    <label>Key</label>
                </field>
            </group>
        </section>
```

Now I am trying to get the data from cms page like this

> {{config path="testsection/settings/key"}}

But I cant access the value using that. Any ideas?

Comment: does it work for values that existed previously?

Comment: Well i didnt check that. But if i add fields after clicking on "add variables" button then it works.

Comment: Then post your finding as an answer?

Comment: @Marius also whenever i am trying to save it its getting changed to something like this `<div class="new class" data-sitekey="domain.com/admin/cms/wysiwyg/directive/___directive/e3tjdXN0b21WYXIgY29kZT1zaXRlX2tleX19/key/5a44f2ce7bbac0b884cde380826ded9c1448ad0957242f6c3b914e0489d95c67/"></div>`  where `data-sitekey` holds the field value. Its weird.

Answer (score 4):

In Magento 2 you can only use a small set of config paths in the `{{config}}` directive in blocks or pages.

**The story behind it (scroll lower for solution):**
The class that handles the `{{...}}` directives for cms blocks and pages is `Magento\Widget\Model\Template\Filter`.  This one extends `Magento\Email\Model\Template\Email`.
In this last class there is this method that handles `{{config}}` directives

```
public function configDirective($construction)
{
    $configValue = '';
    $params = $this->getParameters($construction[2]);
    $storeId = $this->getStoreId();
    if (isset($params['path']) && $this->isAvailableConfigVariable($params['path'])) {
        $configValue = $this->_scopeConfig->getValue(
            $params['path'],
            \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
            $storeId
        );
    }
    return $configValue;
}
```

In order to use a certain config path, the method `isAvailableConfigVariable` needs to return `true`

This method looks like this:

```
private function isAvailableConfigVariable($variable)
{
    return in_array(
        $variable,
        array_column($this->configVariables->getData(), 'value')
    );
}
```

so it checks if the path you send is returned by `\Magento\Email\Model\Source\Variables::getData`.

That's why only a small set of config paths can be used.

**Now the solution**
Create an `after` plugin for the method `\Magento\Email\Model\Source\Variables::getData`

Add this to the `di.xml` of one of your modules

```
<type name="Magento\Email\Model\Source\Variables">
    <plugin name="add-test-credentials" type="[Vendor]\[Module]\Plugin\Model\Source\VariablePlugin" />
</type>
```

and create the plugin class:

```
<?php
namespace [Vendor]\[Module]\Plugin\Model\Source;

use Magento\Email\Model\Source\Variables;

class VariablePlugin
{
    /**
     * @param Variables $subject
     * @param $data
     * @return array
     */
    public function afterGetData(Variables $subject, $data)
    {
        $data[] = [
            'value' => 'testsection/settings/key',
            'label' => __('Credentials for test settings') //give it a label that suits you best. This will be listed in the insert custom var popup in the cms pages and blocks (see image below)
        ];
        return $data;
    }
}
```

[image: insert custom variable to block or page]

Answer (score 3):

**This code is tested in Magento 2.4. it is working fine.**

You need to add a variables in the di.xml

> **[Vendor]/[Module]/etc/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Variable\Model\Source\Variables">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="configPaths" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="[Section_Id]/[Group_Id]" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="[Section_Id]/[Group_Id]/[Field_Id_1]" xsi:type="string">1</item>
                    <item name="[Section_Id]/[Group_Id]/[Field_Id_2]" xsi:type="string">1</item>
                    <item name="[Section_Id]/[Group_Id]/[Field_Id_3]" xsi:type="string">1</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>
```

You can add following line in CMS page or blocks

> **{{config path='Section_Id/Group_Id/Field_Id_1'}}**
>
> **{{config path='Section_Id/Group_Id/Field_Id_2'}}**
>
> **{{config path='Section_Id/Group_Id/Field_Id_3'}}**

Comment: This appears to be the correct answer although type `Magento\Variable\Model\Source\Variables` didn't work for me (in Magento 2.4.3), I used this: `Magento\Variable\Model\Config\Structure\AvailableVariables`. Works as expected

Answer (score 2):

You could also add your field in the di.xml file, then it will be available in your email templates.

`<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Variable\Model\Source\Variables">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="configPaths" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="general/store_information" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="general/store_information/custom_config" xsi:type="string">1</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>`

In email template :

```
{{config path="general/store_information/custom_config"}}
```

Magento does it in vendor/magento/module-variable/etc/di.xml

Answer (score 1):

If for some reasons previous answers like this https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/325492/86806 doesn't work for you can try like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Variable\Model\Config\Structure\AvailableVariables">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="configPaths" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="[Section_Id]/[Group_Id]" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="[Section_Id]/[Group_Id]/[Field_Id_1]" xsi:type="string">1</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>
```

I change `<type name="Magento\Variable\Model\Source\Variables">` on `<type name="Magento\Variable\Model\Config\Structure\AvailableVariables">` 
I tested it in magento 2.4.6-p2

Comment: I'm on Magento 2.4.6-p2 and this was exactly what I was looking for, and it works!  Thank you!